# The member role cannot find the deletion information of CnosDB

Tags: database, cnosdb

### 0. Env

```
version: cnosdb 2.4.0, 
revision: 2fd7e8d02516beb696472d9bee115d948c224d1c
mode: 3m2d
```

### 1. Reproduce step

```
(1) start 3m2d cluster;
(2) create tenant t001;
(3) create database db001 in t001;
(4) create user u001, add tenant t001 as member;
(5) root: drop db001;
(6) u001: select * from information_schema.resource_status;
```

According to the above operation process, I cannot get the deletion information. Which step is problematic?